# Is there a way to remove a parameter from all calls to a method in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, refactoring, visual-studio-2022

Developing a ZWCad API using .NET and C#, Visual Studio.

I have started with this class constructor.

```
internal class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> BarFromThisFoo { get; set; }

    public double MaxYBar { get; set; } = 0;
    
    // Some other properties

    public Foo(bool autoGetBar)
    {
        if(autoGetBar)
        {
            BarFromThisFoo = GetBarFromThisFoo();
        }       

        // Get some other properties
    }
}
```

Now, I'm overloading the constructor and one of the methods to the following:

```
internal class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> BarFromThisFoo { get; set; }

    public double MaxYBar { get; set; } = 0;
    
    // Some other properties

    public Foo()
    {
         BarFromThisFoo = GetBarFromThisFoo();

        // Get some other properties
    }

    public Foo(ObjectId[] selectedObjets)
    {
         BarFromThisFoo = GetBarFromThisFoo(selectedObjets);

        // Get some other properties
    }

}
```

The problem is that I have 12 calls to this method and naturally getting errors in all off them since I don't have anymore the bool parameter in the constructor. And all the refactoring options that I have from visual studio point me to add the bool parameter the constructor, which I don't want.

Is there some refactoring option or tool to this situations?

For now I'm using the Find and Replace tool, but it is kind of slow when having multiple files.

I also have looked for Visual Studio extensions but haven't tried none since none of them seems to cover this situation.

Comment: In VS Studio '22 with Ctrl+Shift+F you can find all the "Foo([^.]+)" calls and you can replace them with find and replace tool set to all files. If you don't have use for Foo(boolean) calls why would you leave in the code. If you have no problem leaving them you can call Foo() default constructor in Foo(bool) constructor which is not a good practice but in the end solves your problem.

Comment: Resharper has a "Change Signature" feature that support this.

Comment: @Bandi Yes, i'm aware of the Find and Replace tool. That's what I'm uisng but as I've mentioned it can be kind of slow when having multiple files in the solution. Thanks

Comment: @JonasH I have looked at reshaper but haven't tried it. Guess I'l have to take some time to go throug the trial. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official document can be found here: [Change a method signature refactoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/change-method-signature?view=vs-2022)

1. Right click on the method, choose the **Quick Actions** menu. Don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, otherwise you may not see the second menu item. (but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> works, maybe it's a bug)

   [image: Step1]
2. Choose the **Change signature** menu.

   [image: Step2]
3. In the dialog, you can click the **Remove** button to remove parameters.

   [image: Step3]
4. If you need to add a new parameter, click the **Add** button, in the new dialog, you can specify the parameter type, name, and the value passed by at the call sites.

   [image: Step4]